# NAS: 100% system (kernel) cpu usage

Tags: kernel, cpu, io, load, nas

I have a single core `NAS My Live Duo`. It runs `Debian lenny` release.
I found via `htop` utility that it constantly use 100% of `red` cpu without any noticeable process to eat it.

Than I checked via `iostat -xkt 1` for more details and found this output:

```
03/01/15 11:35:12
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00  100.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00  780.00    0.00 49920.00     0.00   128.00     0.41    0.53   0.52  40.80
sdb               0.00     0.00  780.00    0.00 49920.00     0.00   128.00     0.36    0.47   0.47  36.40
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
md3               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

How to find what causes this high io usage in order to fix that?

Comment: Another possible cause is a software raid, which I do have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem there `df -H`

One of your disks is fully loaded.

All you need is `lsof | grep deleted | less`

This help you to understand what files were deleted and "keeps in memory" by processes.

For solve your problem you should restart process that holds deleted files.